# How to use XPATH correctly?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I’m using `scrapy` to scrape bookmaker and I have trouble in using `XPATH`

How do I to scrape `3.40, 1.58, 5.50` by using a node contains 'bet365'

ex:

```
//a[contains(text(),'bet365')]/../preceding-sibling::td
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1xHu.png

Comment: Please don't post pictures of html. Use the snippet tool via [edit]

Comment: Also, include the actual results you are getting with the XPath expressions you have tried so far, and include the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct xpath.

```
//a[.='bet365']/ancestor::div[@class='l']/parent::td/following-sibling::*//div[contains(@onmouseout,'delayHideTip')]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you show it looks like you could use [css selector in scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html) of

```
#odds-data-table td [onmouseover]
```